# What does "be representable in execution character set" mean?

Tags: c++, char, language-lawyer

The type of a character literal is specified by the following rule:

> A character literal that does not begin with u8, u, U, or L is an ordinary character literal. An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set. An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal, or **an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character set**, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an implementation-defined value.

So consider the below example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    auto c = '\u0080';
    std::cout<< typeid(c).name();
}
```

The type of `c` is `int` (reported by [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/8qrMqP)). Why is the type of `c` is `int`?

According to the grammar of **c-char**, it's defined as:

> c-char:
>
> > - any member of the source character set except the single-quote ', backslash , or new-line character
> > - escape-sequence
> > - **universal-character-name**

In this example, `\u0080` is a **universal-character-name** which is a single c-char. So the ordinary character literal `'\u0080'` does not contain more than one c-char. The default execution character set of GCC is UTF-8. That means, `\u0080` is completely representable by the UTF-8 set. Why does GCC specify the type of `c` to be `int`? Although I know such a code point value cannot be represented by a char object, it's not what the above rule states. Is it a GCC bug or something I'm misunderstanding? How to interpret "be representable in the execution character set"?

Comment: I think this is called a [_non-encodable character literal_](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#1). See also [_Non-encodable characters_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal#Non-encodable_characters) on cppreference.

Comment: @heapunderrun That's not the standard.

Comment: True, but the first link I provided is the current working draft of the standard, and I think the emphasis is on "_cannot be encoded as a **single code unit**_" there.

Comment: @heapunderrun `A single code unit` seems to be underspecified in that draft. What does it refer to? Is there any normative definition for the wording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The default execution character set of GCC is UTF-8.

And therein lies the problem. Namely, this is not true. Or at least, not in the way that the C++ standard means it.

The standard defines the "basic character set" as a collection of 96 different characters. However, it does not define an encoding for them. That is, the character "A" is part of the "basic character set". But the *value* of that character is not specified.

When the standard defines the "basic execution character set", it adds some characters to the basic set, but it also defines that there is a mapping from a character to a value. Outside of the NUL character being 0 however (and that the digits have to be encoded in a contiguous sequence), it lets implementations decide for themselves what that mapping is.

Here's the issue: UTF-8 is not a "character set" by any reasonable definition of that term.

Unicode is a character set; it defines a series of characters which exist and what their meanings are. It also each character in the Unicode character set a unique numeric value (a Unicode codepoint).

UTF-8 is... not that. UTF-8 is a scheme for *encoding* characters, typically in the Unicode character set (though it's not picky; it can work for any 21-bit number, and it can be extended to 32-bits).

So [when GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Character-sets.html) says:

> [The execution character set] is under control of the user; the default is UTF-8, matching the source character set.

This statement makes no sense, since as previously stated, UTF-8 is a text encoding, not a character set.

What seems to have happened to GCC's documentation (and likely GCC's command line options) is that they've conflated the concept of "execution character set" with "narrow character encoding scheme". UTF-8 is how GCC encodes narrow character strings by default. But that's different from saying what its "execution character set" is.

That is, you can use UTF-8 to encode *just* the basic execution character set defined by C++. Using UTF-8 as your narrow character encoding scheme has no bearing on what your execution character set is.

Note that Visual Studio has a similarly-named option and [makes a similar conflation of the two concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=msvc-160). They call it the "execution character set", but they explain that the *behavior* of the option as:

> The execution character set is the encoding used for the text of your program that is input to the compilation phase after all preprocessing steps.

So... what *is* GCC's execution character set? Well, since their documentation has confused "execution character set" with "narrow string encoding", it's pretty much impossible to know.

So what does the standard *require* out of GCC's behavior? Well, take the rule you quoted and turn it around. A single universal-character-name in a character literal will either be a `char` or an `int`, and it will only be the latter if the universal-character-name names a character *not* in the execution character set. So it's impossible for a system's execution character set to include more characters than `char` has bits to allow them.

That is, GCC's execution character set *cannot* be Unicode in its entirety. It must be some subset of Unicode. It can choose for it to be the subset of Unicode whose UTF-8 encoding takes up 1 `char`, but that's about as big as it can be.

---

While I've framed this as GCC's problem, it's also technically a problem in the C++ specification. The paragraph you quoted *also* conflates the encoding mechanism (ie: what `char` means) with the execution character set (ie: what characters are available to be stored).

This problem has been [recognized and addressed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2029r2.html) by the addition of this wording:

> A non-encodable character literal is a character-literal whose c-char-sequence consists of a single c-char that is not a numeric-escape-sequence and that specifies a character that either lacks representation in the literal's associated character encoding or that cannot be encoded as a single code unit. A multicharacter literal is a character-literal whose c-char-sequence consists of more than one c-char. The encoding-prefix of a non-encodable character literal or a multicharacter literal shall be absent or L. Such character-literals are conditionally-supported.

As these are proposed (and accepted) as resolutions for CWG issues, they also retroactively apply to previous versions of the standard.

Comment: That's the c++23 standard.

Comment: "UTF-8 is... not that. UTF-8 is a scheme for encoding characters, typically in the Unicode character set". Can you give an example on how it different from "Unicode is a character set; it defines a series of characters which exist and what their meanings are. It also each character in the Unicode character set a unique numeric value (a Unicode codepoint)."? What does Unicode do which UTF-8 doesn't? Why are you saying UTF-8 is not a character set?

Comment: @Dmitry: "*Why are you saying UTF-8 is not a character set?*" [Because it's not.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) Calling UTF-8 a character set is like calling a web browser "the Internet". A browser is a way to access the Internet, but it is neither the only way to do so nor the Internet itself. UTF-8 is a way of encoding integers, typically used to encode Unicode codepoints. But UTF-8 does not include the definitions of what those codepoints *mean*. That's Unicode: it defines what characters exist and what their codepoints are. But not how to store them in data streams. That's UTF-8.

Comment: @jackX: "*That's the c++23 standard.*" Technically, it's from a proposal for the C++23 standard. And I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here. It's a proposal addressing several core issues, so it's effectively part of prior versions of the standard too.

Comment: @NicolBolas The standard I used to specify the option `-std=` is C++17 even C++20 has also no modification in [lex.ccon]#2.  Technically, we should stop mentioning c++23 here. Except that, in the other aspects, your answers have resolved the issues here.

Comment: @jackX: "*Technically, we should stop mentioning c++23 here.*" Fixes for defects in a standard are usually applied retroactively.

Comment: @NicolBolas  Wait,  It seems that `a single code unit` has not a normative definition in the c++23 standard.  What does it refer to? `a single code unit` is not necessarily equavalent to `eight-bits code unit` as mentiomed in [intro.memory](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.memory#1), Isn't it?

Comment: @jackX: C++ incorporates the appropriate parts of the Unicode standard by reference, and that standard does specify what a "code unit" is. Please stop trying to read the standard as if all of its words are alien code you're trying to decipher with no context or frame of reference for. It's just English.

Comment: @NicolBolas The Unicode standard defined the `code unit` for UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 respectively. However, it does not define the `code unit` for an execution character set. That's back to the original question. So, how the range a single code unit for **execution character set** can represent?

Comment: @jackX: And where in that text does it refer to a "code unit for an execution character set?" It specifically says, "that specifies a character that either lacks representation in the literal's **associated character encoding** or that cannot be encoded as a single code unit." Nothing here talks about character sets. Encodings however do have code units. And for what it's worth, yes, that paper *also* explains what "associated character encoding" means.

Comment: @NicolBolas "The minimal bit combination that can represent a unit of encoded text for processing or interchange." as stated in [code_unit](https://unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit). So, what is the minimal bit combination for an encoded text that is in the **execution character set**?

Comment: @jackX: It's defined by the implementation when it specifies what the "associated character encoding" for the "execution character set" is. Essentially, this makes GCC's documentation correct by saying that it's specifying the associated character encoding (UTF-8 by default).

Comment: @NicolBolas Assume we specify `UTF-16` as the "associated character encoding" for the "execution character set". Does it mean, when we write `auto c = '\u0080'`, the type of the `c` would be char?

Comment: @jackX: Yes. But `CHAR_BIT` would *also* be 16. And since `char` is required to have a `sizeof` 1, that would half the size of every type that isn't already 8-bits in size. That's almost certainly what GCC would do if you set its narrow encoding to use UTF-16.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you mean, assume `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and a `sizeof int` is 4. If we set `CHAR_BIT ` to 16, then the `sizeof int` would be 2?